# How to run a specific template from multiple templates in a singular yml file with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, config, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes template file that contains multiple temples inside for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  namespace: elastic-foo
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    # all input will come from filebeat, no local logs
    input {
       
    }
    filter {
    
    }
    output {
      
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: elastic-foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.1
        env:
                       
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-config
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-config
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash-service
  namespace: elastic-foo
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5044
    targetPort: 5044
  type: ClusterIP
```

My question is, how can I execute only one template by name
for example :

```
kubectl create -f Service or Deployment or ConfigMap -f my_config.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a feature of Kubectl. You can split them into different files or pipe through a tool like `yq` and use `kubectl create -f -`.

Comment: i know i can split to files , what do you mean pipe through yq ? can i see example ?

Comment: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/file-operators#get-file-index